# Strategy Pattern two usages of @Service duplicate component name

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

Implemented a strategy pattern very simple with the help of Spring Boot:

I have an interface:

```
public interface IOneStrategy {
  void executeTheThing();
}
```

I have an implementation of the strategy One like this:

```
@Service("FIRST")
public class OneStrategyFirst implements IOneStrategy {

  @Override
  public void executeTheThing() {
    System.out.println("OneStrategyFirst.executeTheThing");
  }
}
```

I have a class which consumes the injected implementations:

```
@Service
public class ExecuteStrategyOne {
  private Map<String, IOneStrategy> strategies;

  public void executeStrategyOne(String name) {
    if (!strategies.containsKey(name)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The key " + name + " does not exist.");
    }
    strategies.get(name).executeTheThing();
  }

   
}
```

and those implementations will be injected by Spring boot automatically by using the name `FIRST`, 'SECOND' etc. (assuming that this is simply a String etc. works very well.).

But now I want to implement another strategy via second interface:

```
public interface ITwoStrategy {
  void executeTheThing();
}
```

and the executing service for the strategy:

```
@Service
public class ExecuteStrategyTwo {
  private Map<String, ITwoStrategy> strategies;
  ...
   
}
```

and now the problematic part, because my application uses the same name which should be made part of the key of the above map I want to use the following:

```
@Service("FIRST")
public class TwoStrategyFirst implements ITwoStrategy {

  @Override
  public void executeTheThing() {
    System.out.println("TwoStrategyFirst.executeTheThing");
  }
}
```

This will of course result into an exception based on the duplicate bean name. The name `FIRST` is really needed to make the difference between the implementation.

I already found things about `@Qualifier` which I could use instead of `@Service(FIRST)`

```
@Service
@Qualifier(FIRST)
public class TwoStrategyFirst implements ITwoStrategy {

  @Override
  public void executeTheThing() {
    System.out.println("TwoStrategyFirst.executeTheThing");
  }
}
```

which unfortunately does not inject the classes into the map by using the name of the qualifier just by the name of the class which is not what I intended to do.

Does exist a solution to get the key of the map in the strategy execution the same as with the `@Service("FIRST")`?

Answer (score 0):

I could use a solution via using the Qualifier annotation like this:

```
@Service
@Qualifier(FIRST)
public class TwoStrategyFirst implements ITwoStrategy {
...
}
```

And based on that there is a more or less easy solution via a bit of code:

```
@Service
public class ExecuteStrategyTwo {


  private Map<String, ITwoStrategy> strategies;

  public ExecuteStrategyOne(List<ITwoStrategy> strategies) {
    this.strategies = strategies.stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(k -> k.getClass().getDeclaredAnnotation(Qualifier.class).value(), Function.identity()));
  }
```

This will inject all implementation into the list of the constructor and will be translated into the map by using the qualifier annotation.